# Why does having an `int (*)(float)` point to an `int foo()` trigger a warning, but having an `int (*)(double)` point to it doesn't?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-pointers

I have this piece of code:

```c
int foo() { return 0; }
int main()
{
    int (*float_function)(float) = foo;
}
```

When compiled using `x86-64 GCC 12.2`, with `-Wall`, it produces the warning ([Link](https://godbolt.org/z/j3zEse6WP)):

> warning: initialization of 'int (*)(float)' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)()' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

But, when I change from `float` to `double` ([Link](https://godbolt.org/z/nz1darMdT)):

```c
int foo(){ return 0;}
int main()
{
    int (*double_function)(double) = foo;
}
```

The warning is now gone.

But I think that both of these should get a warning.

Am I wrong somewhere? Why does GCC not complain about the second example?

Comment: For background info, there is a nice discussion about function pointer compatibility here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559581/casting-a-function-pointer-to-another-type

Comment: I knew the answer of this question (it's because of default argument promotions which are performed on calls to non prototyped functions) - but I didn't know for type compatibility between non prototyped and prototyped functions - so thanks for posting this question.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Compatibility of function types that does not include a prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58353041/1187415)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`int foo()` is declared without specifying its parameters. This is an obsolescent feature that lets you call it with any arguments. When calling the function, integer arguments are promoted to `int` (if needed), and `float` arguments are promoted to `double`.

Due to this, it's impossible for this function to receive a `float` parameter, which makes it incompatible with `int (*)(float)`, but not with `int (*)(double)`.

If you want a function that takes no parameters, declare it as `int foo(void)` which will make it incompatible with both.

Note that even with `double`, the code is not valid C because `int foo() {...}` is a function definition, so the compiler knows that it has no parameters (see chux's comment below for the standard reference). Most compilers still allow it.

If you replace it with a declaration `int foo();` and place the definition elsewhere then the above is correct. In that case, the relevant standard quote (C17 6.7.6.3/15) is:

> For two function types to be compatible, [...] If one type has
> a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a
> function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, [...] the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions.

Comment: Nice explanation. Having a function declared without specified parameters can often lead to confusion. It can be caught by enabling the warning [`-Wstrict-prototypes`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) (no, `-Wall` does not enable all warnings).

Comment: interjay, C11 § 6.7.6.3 14 has "An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters." contradicts.  A function _definition_ as `int foo(){ return 0;}` should be the same as `int foo(void){ return 0;}`.  I suspect the compiler used does not following this specification.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think you're right and this shouldn't compile. But both gcc and clang do allow this, even in `-pedantic` mode.

Comment: The UB will only hit when the function is called. The C standard explicitly allows conversation to prototype-less function. Types **are** compatible. The compiler is too overzealous with this warning.

Comment: @tstanisl "the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions." - from the standard (6.7.6.3/15), regarding compatibility with a prototype-less function type. Besides, even if the standard did allow it, this is exactly the sort of thing that warnings are supposed to catch.

Comment: @interjay, Interesting. Definitively, you should include this citation in the answer. It precisely answers why `int(double)` and `int()` are compatible while `int(float)` and `int()` are not. Anyway, I've learned something today, thx.

Comment: "(no, -Wall does not enable all warnings)" [wat.](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/wat) Is there some `-Wone-all-to-rule-them-all` which reliably catches all these foot guns?